# Quelle est l'anomalie dans « nous allons nous en être sortis » ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, auxiliaires

Cette phrase me semble erronée, mais je n'arrive pas à comprendre pourquoi elle « sonne » erronée.

Est-ce qu'il y a effectivement quelque chose d'anormal dans la phrase?

À titre informatif, la phrase initiale qui détonnait à mes oreilles est « On va s'en être sortis. », mais celle indiquée comme titre me sonne tout autant erronée.

Comment: Si la phrase est adéquate, elle détonne probablement car « en » substitue « cette situation », ou un autre concept connexe.

Comment: Ce n'est pas *sortis* qui est incorrect? On devrait écrire *sorti*, non?

Comment: Pour moi, ça ne détonne pas plus que « Nous allons avoir mangé »

Comment: @Joubarc Pour moi, « nous allons avoir mangé » détonne tout autant.

Comment: @Evpok : Effectivement, je suis plus que médiocre en accord(s?) et en orthographe! À lire d'avantage en français plus qu'en anglais, je m'améliorerais surement!

Comment: @Gilles : c'est exactement ce que je sous-entendais...

Comment: @Evpok En France, on est originaux avec les accords...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La phrase est grammaticalement correcte, mais elle me semble moi aussi bizarre.

Je pense que ce qui est gênant, de manière générale, c'est la combinaison du [futur proche](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futur_proche) avec le passé composé (ou plutôt l'infinitif passé). Le futur proche a un [aspect inchoatif](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_inchoatif) (merci Wikipédia) : « s'en être sorti » est un évènement qui nous arrivera bientôt et que le présent annonce. L'infinitif passé indique quant à lui un fait accompli, dont la date n'est pas connue. « Nous allons nous en être sortis » suggère à la fois qu'il y a un rapport temporel observable entre le présent et le moment de s'en sortir (futur proche), et qu'il n'y a pas de relation entre le moment présent et le moment de s'en sortir (participe passé). Contradiction.

Il me paraît naturel de dire « nous allons nous en sortir », qui annonce le prochain évènement « s'en sortir ». C'est le seul moyen pour que « nous nous en sommes sortis » devienne vrai.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour cette explication. De plus, j'ajouterais que cette réponse est suffisamment longue pour être instructive, mais juste assez courte pour rester simple!

Comment: Après avoir lu l'explication, il est difficile de comprendre pourquoi la construction fonctionne avec la conclusion qu'il y a une contradiction. Par ailleurs, quelle est la contradiction en question ?

Comment: @GAMPUB Justement, la construction ne fonctionne pas, en tout cas pas sans un contexte pour la faire passer comme effet de style.

Answer (score 1):

Je dirais « nous allons nous en sortir ». « En être sorti » est possible dans « il faut en être sorti avant de commenter publiquement » p.e.

Edit: l'infinitif passé est (être sorti plutôt que sortir) s'emploie pour un fait passé par rapport à un autre.  Il faut donc un autre fait pour que l'expression tienne. « Nous allons nous en être sorti avant l'arrivée de la pluie. » me semble correct (bien que « Nous allons en être sorti avant l'arrivée de la pluie. » me semble sonner mieux) et avec une notion d'achèvement que « Nous allons nous en sortir avant l'arrivée de la pluie. » n'a pas.

Re-Edit: Entendu en rentrant chez moi hier soir, « C'est bien, tu vas avoir fini avant que papa n'arrive » (eh non..., mais c'est une autre histoire).

Comment: Le dernier re-Edit semble tout à fait normal, pas du tout une autre histoire... Arrivé à ce point, la réponse initiale ne semble plus constituer l'essentiel de ce qui est dit. Est-ce qu'on pourrait avoir une version éditée globalement ?

Comment: @GAMPUB, le coeur de ma réponse est le premier edit.  Le second est une note amusante sans aucun rapport avec le fond, un usage pris sur le vif de l'infinitif passé. Le c''est une autre histoire" est juste une allusion au fait que l'énoncé était faux, je suis rentré avant que notre enfant ait terminé ses devoirs puisque j'ai pu surprendre la remarque.

Answer (score -1):

Il me semble que tu as mélangé les phrases suivantes:

s'en sortir (nous allons nous en sortir)

s'en être sorti (nous nous en sommes sortis)

C'est pour ça qu'il a un aspect un peu bizarre.

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait mélange, ça m'a juste l'air d'être *nous nous en sommes sortis* au futur proche avec *aller* comme [semi-auxiliaire](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Verbe_semi-auxiliaire).

Comment: Je n'ai pas dit que la phrase n'était pas correcte, simplement qu'elle me semble un peu bizarre car c'est un mélangé de deux temps que ne se dit pas ensemble souvent. Et je suis toujours de cet avis.